# Getting ""(null): can't open file '/cygdrive/c/abc/repo': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"" error when trying to use a file in python3.7 venv

Tags: windows, git, windows-10, repo

We have repo tool (http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo) ,which looks to be a python script, on windows-10, which works fine without any virtual env enabled i.e in python2.7 as default version
Refer output below

```
C:\abc>python --version
Python 2.7.18

C:\abc>ls -l
drwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators           abcd-01234+None     0 May  1 21:00 abc
-rwxrwx---+ 1 Administrators           abcd-01234+None 27250 May  8 22:38 repo

C:\abc>bash -c "/cygdrive/c/abc/repo help init"
Usage: repo init -u url [options]

Options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit

  Logging options:
    -q, --quiet         be quiet

  Manifest options:
    -u URL, --manifest-url=URL
                        manifest repository location
    -b REVISION, --manifest-branch=REVISION
                        manifest branch or revision
    -m NAME.xml, --manifest-name=NAME.xml
                        initial manifest file
    --mirror            create a replica of the remote repositories rather
                        than a client working directory
```

But same command/tool doesn't work in python3.7 virtual environment enabled

```
(python37_virtualenv) C:\abc>bash -c "/cygdrive/c/abc/repo help init"
(null): can't open file '/cygdrive/c/abc/repo': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

(python37_virtualenv) C:\abc>
```

Expecting same output to be produced in python3.7 virtual environment enabled as well

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the path you are attempting to achieve is `C:\abc\cygdrive\c\abc\repo`, try the command you used, but without the first slash, so `bash -c "cygdrive/c/abc/repo help init"`. I did testing with Python paths, and it seemed with relative path directories, it does not want a slash before it.

If this does not work, try putting in the absolute path instead.